# If f is a biyective function then f inverse no necessarily preserve the order?

Tags: functions, order-theory

How can we prove that if two partially ordered sets and f is a bijective function then the inverse of f does not necessarily preserve the order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f:\{0,1\} -> \{0,1\} $ be such that $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Its inverse does not preserve the order.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el orden en tu ejemplo?

Comment: @JasonAndres Pienso che sería el orden natural : $0 < 1$

Comment: @C. Caruvana Sea $ f: \{0,1\}  \to \{0,1\}$ y $ f^{-1}:  \{0,1\}  \to \{0,1\} $  donde $f(0)=1$  y $ f(1)=0$ como $0\le1$ pero $1\nless0$ por lo tanto $ f^{-1}$ no preserva el orden. ¿ qué piensas de los argumentos de este contraejemplo?¿está bien escrito?

Comment: @JasonAndres Sí, me parece bien. También podrías incluir que $f^{-1}(0) = 1$ y $f^{-1}(1) = 0$ explícitamente.

Comment: @C.Caruvana muchas gracias por su explicación.

Comment: @JasonAndres Parece un argumento correcto.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want an example where $f$ is order-preserving. If you take ${\cal X} = (X, \le)$ to be any partially ordered set that is not totally ordered, then you can extend $\le$ to a total order ${\cal X}' = (X, \le')$  (computer scientists call this [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)). The identity function on $X$ is then an order-preserving function from ${\cal X}$ to ${\cal X}'$ whose inverse is not order-preserving. The simplest specific example is to take $X = \{0, 1\}$ and then take $\cal X$ to be $X$ ordered so that $0$ and $1$ are incomparable and ${\cal X}'$ to be $X$ ordered with its usual ordering as a subset of $\Bbb{N}$.